# Nested lists CSS overriding styling (#id + class)

Tags: css, list, nested

A particular nested list, with parent `div id` and list items with different class... I can't make it to assign correctly background colors.

For example:

```
<div id="sidebar" class="widget-area">
<div class="theiaStickySidebar">
    <aside id="advanced_sidebar_menu-2" class="widget advanced-sidebar-menu">
        <ul class="parent-sidebar-menu">
            <li class="current_page_ancestor">
                <a href="http://somesite/about-us/">About Us</a>
                <ul class="child-sidebar-menu">
                    <li class="page_item">
                       <a href="http://somesite/about-us/welcome/">Welcome</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page_item current_page_item">
                       <a href="http://somesite/about-us/mission-and-philosophy/">Mission and philosophy</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </aside>
</div>
```

What CSS code would you use to change background colour of each li/a item belonging to class `current_page_ancestor`, `page_item` and `current_page_item`(each one should have different colors)

Comment: Have you got a JSFiddle example with all the HTML/CSS pertaining to your question we can have a look at? http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For first `a` you can use `>` or direct-child selector and for others you can just select with `parentClass`->`a`

```css
.current_page_ancestor > a {
  color: black;
}
.page_item a {
  color: green;
}
.page_item.current_page_item a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar" class="widget-area">
  <div class="theiaStickySidebar">
    <aside id="advanced_sidebar_menu-2" class="widget advanced-sidebar-menu">
      <ul class="parent-sidebar-menu">
        <li class="current_page_ancestor">
          <a href="http://somesite/about-us/">About Us</a>
          <ul class="child-sidebar-menu">
            <li class="page_item">
              <a href="http://somesite/about-us/welcome/">Welcome</a>
            </li>
            <li class="page_item current_page_item">
              <a href="http://somesite/about-us/mission-and-philosophy/">Mission and philosophy</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </aside>
  </div>
```

Comment: Sorry but it's not working, I believe that there's a specificity for div id #sidebar that will win :-/. I need to override somehow

Comment: `.current_page_ancestor > a` can be just left as `.current_page_ancestor a` since the subsequent rules will override it.

Comment: @NenadVracar, I think Riccardo wants to change background colours

Comment: I've got it to work! It looked like if it wasn't working because the visited color was always the same! Changed your snippet with bakcground-color, and it is working! Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. To change visited links colors you can use `a:visited`

Comment: Last question, however your rules will change attributes of the a, but not the background of the li or ul. I can achieve this referencing #sidebar in the stylesheet, but it will override everything, also your rules!

Comment: @Nenad, I don't want to color all the div #sidebar with the same color, but just the li , because the li have some padding, and coloring the a only it will not be sufficient. The problem remains for the list items (li) background...

Comment: Yes that is the idea! But we must limit the scope to what's inside #sidebar....otherwise we will spoil all the lists in the page....

Comment: Use `#sidebar li` and `#sidebar li li`

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul {
  /* reset lists */
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}



/* specific styles */

.page_item a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  color: white;
  background-color: #333;
}
.page_item a:hover,
.page_item.current_page_item a{
  background-color: #666;
}

.parent-sidebar-menu {
  width: 200px;
}

.current_page_ancestor > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: green;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: right;
}

.current_page_ancestor > a:before {
  content: "Back to >> ";
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar" class="widget-area">
  <div class="theiaStickySidebar">
    <aside id="advanced_sidebar_menu-2" class="widget advanced-sidebar-menu">
      <ul class="parent-sidebar-menu">
        <li class="current_page_ancestor">
          <a href="http://somesite/about-us/">About Us</a>
          <ul class="child-sidebar-menu">
            <li class="page_item">
              <a href="http://somesite/about-us/welcome/">Welcome</a>
            </li>
            <li class="page_item current_page_item">
              <a href="http://somesite/about-us/mission-and-philosophy/">Mission and philosophy</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </aside>
  </div>
</div> <!-- #sidebar -->
```

This is slightly different in that instead of using each class to do something different I am using similar things to do the same thing and changing based on state change.  The ancestor page is treaded differently than the child sidebar menu.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you reset only lists in #sidebar?

Comment: It is a fairly common practice to reset lists in this manner, it could be more refined but I was in a hurry.  I include a reset file in each project usually normalize.  As to your specific question you can reset any style for any element you wish.